# Angular SSR: Cannot match any routes error when URL Segment is 'robots.txt'

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

Hello I have been following the Angular guide to use SSR, https://angular.io/guide/universal
It showed me the following error, I have been looking for a solution and I have not found anything. I publish the solution in case someone else has the same thing happen to me.

```
Angular is running in development mode.
./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs:3655
        return new ɵRuntimeError(4002 /* RuntimeErrorCode.NO_MATCH */, (typeof ngDevMode === 'undefined' || ngDevMode) &&
               ^


RuntimeError: NG04002: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'robots.txt'
    at noMatchError (./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs:3655:16)
    at e (./node_modules/@angular/router/fesm2022/router.mjs:3670:28)
    at onError (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/catchError.js:13:51)
    at _error (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/operators/OperatorSubscriber.js:43:21)
    at error (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:60:18)
    at _error (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:84:30)
    at error (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:60:18)
    at _error (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:84:30)
    at error (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:60:18)
    at OperatorSubscriber.Subscriber._error (./node_modules/rxjs/dist/cjs/internal/Subscriber.js:84:30) {
  code: 4002
}

Node.js v20.2.0
A server error has occurred.
node exited with 1 code.
```

Use the following commands
`ng add @nguniversal/express-engine`
`npm run dev:ssr`